# PostgreSQL Sum and Percent of Total Subquery

Tags: postgresql

Table has sales and i'm trying to calculate the sales dollars and percent of total.

```
WITH t1 AS (
    SELECT
    product_id,
    sum(financial_charge_cents) as cents
    FROM "account_charges"
    WHERE account_id = 5
    AND status = 'Charged'
    GROUP BY product_id
    ORDER BY cents DESC
)
SELECT 
    product_id, 
    cast(cents as money) / 100.0 AS dollars, 
    cents / (sum(cents) OVER (PARTITION BY product_id)) as percent
FROM t1
ORDER BY dollars DESC
```

but this is returning all the percents to be `1` and not sure why.

not sure if this is a type problem or what.

Answer (score 1):

`OVER (PARTITION BY produuct_id)` causes that the sums are the same as `cents`. You do not need partitions:

```
SELECT 
    product_id, 
    cast(cents as money) / 100.0 AS dollars, 
    cents* 1.0 / (sum(cents) OVER ()) as percent
FROM t1
ORDER BY dollars DESC
```

Note, I have added `*1.0` to get numeric results. Skip it if `cents` are numeric (not integer).